# grep behavior with patterns of '-' character

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

Actual answer to my question might be very simple(probably I just have to read the reg-ex tutorials again). But this is more on the behavior which I saw with grep and '-' character.

I've a patch file(diff.txt) which contains entries like.

```
--- a/path/to/xyz

+++ b/path/to/modified/xyz
```

Now, for some reason I wanted to grep all lines in the file which exactly contains "---" pattern.

After simple grep commands failed to give me what I wanted, I tried below three commands:

```
$ grep "-" ./diff.txt
```

The above one yields the results showing all the existence of '-' symbol(single occurence, multiple occurence ).

```
$ grep  "--" ./diff.txt
```

This one yields nothing. No output. Grep got stuck in some loop?(trying to find out something which is not there?). Had to Ctrl-C to stop the command.

```
$ grep "---"  ./diff.txt
```

After this one, Grep complains of **Unrecognized pattern** and prints the help message.

In case, someone is wondering, I did try the same command with a "+++" pattern and a simple grep command worked like a charm:

```
$ grep "+++" ./diff.txt   --> output all the lines correctly.
```

I'll appreciate if someone could explain this strange behavior with '-' character.

Answer (score 3):

Grep may be trying to interpret your pattern as an option.

Use `-e` to make it explicit:

```
grep -e --- ./diff.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

A pattern starting with a `-` is interpreted as an *option*.

`--` means *end of options*.

Use `--` to tell grep that any following arguments are not options.

```
grep -- pattern path...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your pattern starts with a dash it's being interpretted as an option. Either explicitly indicate the end of options with the `--` option, or explicitly indicate that your pattern *is* a pattern with the `-e` option.

```
$ echo -e "---abc\ndef\n---ghi\njkl"
---abc
def
---ghi
jkl

$ echo -e "---abc\ndef\n---ghi\njkl" | grep -- ---
---abc
---ghi

$ echo -e "---abc\ndef\n---ghi\njkl" | grep -e ---
---abc
---ghi
```

(The `-e` option to the `echo` command allows c-style escapes like `\n`.)

Comment: @konsolebox So now you're following me around handing out non-deserved -1's? Pathetic! To answer your "question", none of the other answers were complete. Now go away!

Comment: Too bad but you're wrong. You're not worth following around. I only noticed it from checking my updates. Our answers were complete enough. You don't add anything significant besides giving obvious examples.

Comment: To add more to your assumptions, I find -no one- in SO worth following or looking up to. After all most people here learned their skills from other people's answers and from following wiki tutorials, etc. None have made significantly stable practices by their own. Don't include me as one of you. You guys would always be newcomers to me.